# "Like swimming in ___" honey?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms, phrase-requests

My supervisor and I had a discussion about my thesis progress this morning, and he described my writing progress:

> Like swimming in _____.

I have no idea about the word he said, then he changed the expression into “swimming in honey”. I have spent half an hour on Google to figure out that word and failed.

- What is the missing word from that phrase?

Comment: *Treacle* or *molasses*?

Comment: Many thanks, Dan. I think what he said is treacle, cheers.

Comment: The point, of course, is that such substances are quite viscous, and so swimming in them would be difficult to impossible.

Comment: @ Hot licks There is an article from Quora " Is it possible to swim in honey?", and that really shows my writing situation. I hope it is difficult not impossible to finish this race.

Comment: He's basically saying that your progress is slow. There are many expressions like this out there, the most common being: "Slower than molasses going uphill in January."

Comment: @DanBron why not write the answer, you only need to write two lines and, you could make it a CW. Then someone with more time can add references, citations, history *blah*, *blah*... We can then safely say the OP has an answer and "lock" it. Or... we can migrate the question to ELL.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok, good idea that I can post less-than-substantiated answers as community wiki, where the answer is obvious enough to most native speakers.  For future cases, you may feel free to do the same for any of my comments (Plus, with CW, you're not even "stealing" rep from me, as you won't earn any. Doesn't matter because I don't care for the rep anyway, but it might put some of your own qualms at ease.)

Comment: @DanBron I thought by now it would have migrated. I think this approach could work. But now I'm too tired to even think straight. Maybe tomorrow morning I'll add something extra.

Comment: What you are asking for here is a guessing game. You already know what your tutor wrote. How should anyone else know? Sorry, but this sort of question is not welcome.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I did not registered for a guessing game. I wanted to learn native expression.

Comment: @emdms this stack exchange is not for learning native expressions, that would be the English Language Learners stack exchange.

Comment: @V0ight Sorry then, I will read through FAQ then come back.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *like ᴠᴇʀʙing through **molasses*** (AmE) or *... through **treacle*** (BrE) is commonly employed to convey the idea of very slow progress.

Typically, this is not due to active resistance, rather it is used reflectively, as a observation made in hindsight.  The analogy is possible, as [@HotLicks points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334442/like-swimming-in-honey?noredirect=1#comment764757_334442), due to the high viscosity of fluids like molasses, treacle and honey.

Alternatively, another common versions of this idiom is **‘wading through treacle’**, this thick sticky black (or golden) syrup will be unfamiliar with many American English speakers. But if you're a fan of [Harry Potter](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Treacle_tart), you ought to know that his favourite dessert is treacle tart. Google Books reports [1,820 results](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22wading+through+treacle%22&tbm=bks&start=10) for the idiom.

> **[wade through](http://to%20spend%20a%20lot%20of%20time%20and%20effort%20doing%20something%20boring%20or%20difficult,%20especially%20reading%20a%20lot%20of%20information:)**  (Cambridge Dictionaries)
>
> to spend a lot of time and effort doing something boring or difficult, especially reading a lot of information:

Comment: Yeah, I'm not on the desktop/full experience site much, I mostly participate via the mobile app, but when I do jump on a computer, I do my duty and review the queues.  I'll take a look at your answer and vote as needed.